# SecKeychain: sign data with RSA PKCS1 PSS PADDING algorithm

Tags: c++, ssl, openvpn, security-framework

I'm trying to implement c++ external PKI sign method for openvpn client.
I need to sign data with RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING algorithm, but Security framework has no such method.

There is my function:

```cpp
void MacStore::sign(const std::string &data, std::string &sig, const std::string &algorithm,
                    const std::string &hashalg, const std::string &saltlen) {
    SecKeyAlgorithm alg;
    if (!hashalg.empty()) {
        alg = kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureDigestPSSSHA256;
    } else {
        alg = kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureMessagePSSSHA1;
    }
    openvpn::BufferAllocated signdata(256, openvpn::BufferAllocated::GROW);
    openvpn::base64->decode(signdata, data);
    SecKeyRef pkey;
    OSStatus status = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey((SecIdentityRef)identity, &pkey);
    if (status) {
        // error
        return;
    }
    auto isSupported = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(pkey, kSecKeyOperationTypeSign, alg);
    std::cout << (isSupported ? "supported" : "not supported") << std::endl;
    auto dataToSign = CFStringCreateWithCString(nullptr, buf_c_str(signdata), kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    auto dataToSignPtr = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(nullptr, dataToSign, kCFStringEncodingASCII, 0);

    CFErrorRef err = nullptr;
    auto signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(pkey, alg, dataToSignPtr, &err);
    if (err) {
        return;
    }

    SecCertificateRef cert;
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate((SecIdentityRef)identity, &cert);
    SecKeyRef pub;
    SecCertificateCopyPublicKey(cert, &pub);

    int signatureLength = CFDataGetLength(signature);
    openvpn::BufferAllocated signer(signatureLength, openvpn::BufferAllocated::ARRAY);
    auto range = CFRangeMake(0, signatureLength);
    CFDataGetBytes(signature, range, signer.data());
    signer.set_size(signatureLength);

    CFRelease(signature);
    CFRelease(dataToSign);

    sig = openvpn::base64->encode(signer);
    std::cout << "SIGNATURE[" << signatureLength << "]: " << signer.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

On connect server log prints:

```
// Verifies certificate - OK
OpenSSL: error:02000087:rsa routines::salt length recovery failed
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 OpenSSL: error:1C880004:Provider routines::RSA lib
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 OpenSSL: error:0A00007B:SSL routines::bad signature
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Dec 09 12:51:38 server openvpn[29669]: 10.31.154.84:50843 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

My question is: which SecAlgorithm should I choose to produce valid rsa signature?

**UPD**: Verify method with same data to sign returns false(invalid signature) as well...

Comment: `RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING` is not enough, you should ask the guys at the server side which hash algorithms are required for the message and internal MGF1, and if the salt size is identical to the hash size (the common default).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes saltsize and hashalg stored in hashalg and saltlen variables, this is purely syntetic example. I now exactly, that is SHA256 algorithm (32 - saltlen) will be used

Comment: One of the security premises of PSS is that the configuration parameters are known in advance and as of now, I'm still not sure if the MGF1 hash is what is expected. It is usually the same as the data hash. Furthmore, you've output a base 64 signature, and I'm not sure how you've integrated that in SSH. It certainly will expect *bytes*, not base 64.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes openvpn expects signing callback returns base64 encoded signature. I'm not sure that signature was produced correctly, verifying the same signature on client side returns error

Comment: Huh? I thought that OpenVPN uses TLS for authentication? PSS would be available for TLS 1.3, but TLS is a binary protocol which doesn't use base 64. Are you sure that the base64 isn't simply part of a logging procedure creating printable text for human consumption?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in my configuration openvpn use tls auth with TLS1.3, base64 encoded data is not actually used in transport layer, but openvpn client expects that epki method implementation returns base64 data. This data will be decoded again in low-level transport layer later, actually signature is just a raw bytes.

Comment: Ah, alright. Note that the length check happen before the hash check which is last. Beware that you'd expect an error like this if there is a mismatch between the public and private keys, i.e. if they are not part of the same key pair. I'd validate that first (e.g. by looking at the modulus or a hash over the modulus).

Comment: I'm also checking how PSS is handled in TLS 1.3, but it seems [more complicated than I initially hoped for](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/58680/1172). Almost all implementations use ECDSA, so this is not something I've encountered in practice.

Comment: 10Q, I'll check it

Comment: According to "the bear", Thomas Pornin: "In TLS 1.3, MGF1 is used, the two hash functions are the same, and the salt length is equal to the hash output length." That is for the handshake. I'm not entirely sure what the difference is between "SigntareMessage" and "SignatureDigest". Maybe you have to provide a hash instead of the message data to the latter and the message itself to the earlier one.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes signature is invalid in server side because it expects another algorithm. Now I'm trying to find the way how to sign with RSA PKCS1 with PSS padding and SHA256 digest hash...

Comment: Found a problem: ```data``` variable is a base64 encoded data, inputBuffer used it instead of ```signdata``` (decoded data to sign). Thank u for your advices!